# Equally-skilled players play a game!

Tags: probability

Players $\ {P}_{1}, {P}_{2}, {P}_{3},...{P}_{m}$ of equal skill play a game consecutively in pairs as $\ {P}_{1}{P}_{2}, {P}_{2}{P}_{3}, {P}_{3}{P}_{4}, ..., {P}_{m-1}{P}_{m}, {P}_{m}{P}_{1}$ and any player who wins two consecutive games[i.e. $\ k$ and $\ {(k+1)}^{th}$ games] win the match. The chance that the match is won at the $\ {r}^{th}$ game is $\ \frac{1}{64}$. Then $\ r$ is

That is the problem. I have worked to get $\ r=9$ which is the right answer. What I did was, nothing smart. I just wrote down possible cases, for smaller cases like 3rd, 4th, 5th game, and then kind of generalize which gave the correct answer. Is there a smart or a better way to approach this problem?

The probabilities for the first few cases are(as I got them):
4th---$\ \frac{3}{16}$,
5th---$\ \frac{2}{16}$,
6th---$\ \frac{1}{16}$,
7th---$\ \frac{3}{64}$,
8th---$\ \frac{2}{64}$,
9th---$\ \frac{1}{64}$
I haven't calculated it for 10th, but from the pattern, it should be $\ \frac{3}{256}$. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Let $p_r$ be the probability that the match is won on the $r^\text{th}$ (with player $r$ winning the $r-1^\text{th}$ and $r^\text{th}$ games) and
- let  $s_r$ be the probability that the match has not been won by the $r^\text{th}$ game and player $r+1$ won the $r^\text{th}$ game and
- let $t_r$ be the probability that the match has not been won by the $r^\text{th}$ game and player $r$ won the $r^\text{th}$ game

Then  $$p_r = \frac12 s_{r-1}$$
$$s_r = \frac12 s_{r-1}+\frac12 t_{r-1}$$
$$t_r = \frac12 t_{r-1}$$

Since $p_1=0$, $s_1=\dfrac12$, $t_1=\dfrac12$, it is an easy induction to show $t_r=\dfrac1{2^r}$, $s_r=\dfrac r{2^r}$ and $p_r=\dfrac{r-1}{2^r}$

So I think some of your calculations may be wrong for $p_r$: I get $p_6=\dfrac{5}{64}$ and $p_8=\dfrac{7}{256}$,

though like you I get $p_9=\dfrac{8}{512}=\dfrac{1}{64}$